# Magento installation problem

Tags: magento2, installation

So I'm trying a fresh installation of Magento but I'm getting the following error when installing via composer. It does not prompt me for credentials or anything. Can anyone help?

[image]

Using -vvv
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please use verbose mode (`-vvv`) to see if you can find some useful information? Otherwise, copy/paste the installation command from the [official website](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/composer.html?lang=en) to prevent copying/pasting any special characters.

Comment: Updated the OP with the -vvv comand info.

Comment: Looks like the directory has some vendor packages that are preventing you to continue, can you please make sure the directory you are installing is completely empty or non-existent?
Also, try to skip the cache with `--no-cache`

Comment: No luck. I think for some reason it's not loading up the auth.json file. Where should this file be placed?

Comment: Removed auth.json and added it again solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

1st thing never use composer as a root.
generate your access keys (public/private keys)from below market place url.

market place url = https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/

now make a dir for magento installation inside html dir and provide permission.
now create auth.josn file inside magento installation dir and add you auth keys here that are copied from market place.

**auth.json**

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "add your public key here",
            "password": "add your private key here"
        }
    }
}
```

after this run this composer create project command from inside your magento installation directory

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but once I try to run the composer command it triggers an error saying that the directory is not empty.

Comment: empty your magento installation dir directory

Comment: It only has the auth.json file

Comment: if you are facing issue like this then just use this below command and it will download 2.4.6 zip and then unzip and install magento

Comment: wget https://magefan.com/media/magento/magento-open-source-2.4.6.zip

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue yesterday here are the steps for a quick fix:

```
Create a new user in the Ubuntu
reinstall the latest composer version 
Restart PHP FPM,Nginx and Elastic Search
```

This will fix your problem, if you require more help then please let me know.